# I want to make a date_picker_timeline. But it's just show date from now to the end of the week

Tags: flutter, datetime

I am using flutter lib **date_picker_timeline**.
`https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline`

Now I want to make a timeline just show date from now(the previous day should be disable, can not chose) to the end of the week.

In their docs, I can not find anything.

[image: 1]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Regards,

I tried to find out on youtube but nothing suit my expected.

Here is my code.

`Container(
child: DatePicker(
DateTime.now(),
width: 60,
height: 80,
controller: _controller,
initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
selectionColor: Colors.black,
selectedTextColor: Colors.white,

```
                  onDateChange: (date) {
                    // New date selected
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedValue = date;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),`
```

What its showing.

[image: 2].

Moreover, How to make it reload and show new week(next week) when DateTime.now() is on Sunday afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

U gotta do it manually, like

```dart
// um using anotherPackage, but condition is similar
void chooseDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? newDateTime = await showRoundedDatePicker(
      context: context,
      height: 340,
      borderRadius: 35,
      initialDate: date,
      firstDate: DateTime(date.year),
      lastDate: DateTime(date.year + 1),
      description: 'Chose your prefered date ..',
    );
    if (newDateTime != null) {
      final monthDays = newDateTime.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
      final date = DateTime.now();
      if (newDateTime.year > date.year ||
          newDateTime.month > date.month ||
          newDateTime.month == date.month && monthDays.day >= date.day - 1) {
        ...........
        ...........
      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (c) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: const Text(
                "This date cannot be selected. This Day passed already !"),
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: const Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```